# selenium gecko driver does not exist in the current directory

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, unit-testing, selenium, automated-tests

Hi there I am trying to do some automation testing in vb.net using selenium but get this error when trying to run my unit test with firefox.

```
Test Name:  WebDriverSample
Test FullName:  AutomationProject.UnitTests.WebDriverSample
Test Source:    C:\Users\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\GasAutomationTesting\V1.0.0.0\Development\AutomationProject\UnitTests.vb : line 49
Test Outcome:   Failed
Test Duration:  0:00:00.0184181

Result StackTrace:  
at OpenQA.Selenium.DriverService.FindDriverServiceExecutable(String executableName, Uri downloadUrl)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService()
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxDriver.CreateService(FirefoxOptions options)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxDriver..ctor(FirefoxOptions options)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxDriver..ctor()
   at AutomationProject.UnitTests.WebDriverSample() in C:\Users\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\GasAutomationTesting\V1.0.0.0\Development\AutomationProject\UnitTests.vb:line 55
Result Message: 
Test method AutomationProject.UnitTests.WebDriverSample threw exception: 
OpenQA.Selenium.DriverServiceNotFoundException: The geckodriver.exe file does not exist in the current directory or in a directory on the PATH environment variable. The driver can be downloaded at https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases.
```

here is my unit test currently

```
    <TestMethod()>
    Public Sub WebDriverSample()

    'Add test logic here
    Dim DRIVER_PATH As String = "C:\Users\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\GasAutomationTesting\GekoDriver"
    Dim driver As IWebDriver
    'Browser
    driver = New FirefoxDriver(DRIVER_PATH)
End Sub
```

I have tried to declare the path to the gecko driver but no luck I have also place the .exe file in the bin folder but im not sure really what to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add till .exe

path = C:\Users\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\PrepayGasAutomationTesting\GekoDriver\geckodriver.exe